# In a .csproj file, what is <None Include="..."> for?

Tags: c#, csproj

How is

```
<None Include="C:\foo.bar" />
```

different from

```
<Content Include="C:\foo.bar" />
```

?

Comment: I had a few `Content`s get changed to `None`s. I think it happened when I renamed files from .ascx to .cshtml when converting to Razor. Changing them back manually fixed some deployment issues I had. Glad I found this.

Comment: Because `None` and `Content` are [Common MSBuild project items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items), the Item metadata names together with `Include="foo.bar"` apply to VS project files of other languages as well.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The MSDN article on the [build action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019#none) property explains the differences.

> **None** - The file is not included in the project output group and is not compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains documentation, such as a Readme file.
>
> **Content** - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content output group. For example, this setting is the default value for an .htm or other kind of Web file.

Comment: Helpful, but why have a "None" item at all, if the file is not to be included in the output? What's the point?

Comment: @JimH44 <None> items are often used to specifically copy files into the output directory, even though they're not in the output group *by default*.  If you select "Copy to Output Directory" -> "Copy Always" for a <None> file, this will cause it to be copied, and you will see the entry added to the project's .csproj file will have a <None> entry for the file.

Comment: So then what is difference between a <None> file with "Copy to Output Directory" -> "Copy Always" and a <Content> file with "Copy to Output Directory" -> "Copy Always"?

Comment: @JimH44 I have some SQL files that I execute in a post-deployment process. Don't need them to be part of the build, nor to be included in the output. I believe there are plenty of such use-cases for this approach.

Comment: This doesn't always work (bug?). I have files that are listed as Content and won't copy with either CopyAlways or CopyIfNewer.

Comment: In completing your answer, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59937570/1817640

Answer (score 34):

One difference is how they get published; "None" items don't get included in a publish, "Content" items do; for example, on the "Application Files" dialog on the Publish tab.

Comment: Not true. At least in the new dot net cli. if you have an item declared as None with a `CopyToOutputDirectory` set to `true` it will get published in a `dotnet publish`

Comment: Not sure either about `PublishState` with `Excluded` description.

Comment: And if you want to exclude the item from being copied to public, set the [`CopyToPublishDirectory="None"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#copytopublishdirectory): https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Aug/24/Keeping-Content-Out-of-the-Publish-Folder-for-WebDeploy#what-works-copytopublishdirectorynever

Answer (score 16):

I am not 100% sure (I read the MSDN description of **Build Action** property) but just copying that answer from MSDN to *StackOverflow* does not answer the question completely for me.

The difference of **None** and **Content** only has an effect on Web projects. For a command line project, WinForm project or UnitTest project (in my case) etc. **None** and **Content** have no different behavior.

MSDN: "project output group" or "Content output group" only terms used in a Web project, right?

Comment: Like you say, seems `None` vs `Content` only has effect for the _publish_ step not the _build_ step. For the build step seems `CopyToOutputDirectory` can be set on either and that controls if the file is copied by the build step. Also seems odd that by default T4 templates are added as `Content` items and not `None` items.

Answer (score 11):

In my situation, my MSBuild file had an `ItemGroup` for image resources that appeared as follows:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\image001.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\image002.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\image003.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\image004.png" />
    <None Include="Resources\image005.png" />
    <None Include="Resources\image006.png" />
    <None Include="Resources\image007.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

While my project was building fine, this left me wondering why I had a mix of `Content` and `None` item type elements in my `ItemGroup`. This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (for Visual Studio 2010) gave me the guidance I was looking for:

> Note that when the resource editor adds an image, it sets **Build
>   Action** to **None**, because the .resx file references the image
>   file. At build time, the image is pulled into the .resources file
>   created out of the .resx file. The image can then easily be accessed
>   by way of the strongly-typed class auto-generated for the .resx file.
>   Therefore, you should not change this setting to **Embedded
>   Resource**, because doing this would include the image two times in
>   the assembly.

**Resolution:** With this guidance, using a text editor, I changed the `Content` item type elements to `None`.

Also, for an overview of MSBuild items, see this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

**Content** files are not included in a build, but are included in a publish.

**None** files are not included in a build or publish, unless they are configured that way by you. For instance, a "Copy to Output Directory" setting of "Always" or "Newer", will cause them to be included in both a build and publish.

Answer (score 3):

I have a project that contains no compilable items (it stores html and javascript for jasmine unit tests).

One day my solution (that contained said project) stopped compiling saying "The target "Build" does not exist in the project".

I added an import to bring in the compiler, which worked fine on my machine but failed using msbuild on the build server.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

I then changed a line from

```
<None Include="SpecRunner.html" />
```

to

```
<Content Include="SpecRunner.html" />
```

and it worked on the build server as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need None in a template project file to include files you define in the .vstemplate  otherwise they are lost in the creation & translation process. They get left behind in the temp folder it uses to build everything and then deleted shortly after.

Answer (score 2):

In my case **.Pubxml** is one of those files among **None** list. It's not meant for solution building or as a static file for web project. But to publish the site to Azure, the configurations are present in this.

As per Microsoft article these are the major types we see among **.csproj** file tags:

> None - The file is not included in the project output group and is not
>   compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that contains
>   documentation, such as a Readme file.
>
> Compile - The file is compiled into the build output. This setting is
>   used for code files.
>
> Content - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content
>   output group. For example, this setting is the default value for an
>   .htm or other kind of Web file.
>
> Embedded Resource - This file is embedded in the main project build
>   output as a DLL or executable. It is typically used for resource
>   files.

Comment: Please comment here, if something is misleading or not clear, Just a down vote doesn't help me improve it any better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I often got error: "None" element name for include "Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml" should be "Content". in my Asp.Net project on Bamboo, and sometime rerun the build can just fix it, so don't know what exactly the problem is

Comment: Hi @BochenLin, the details you mentioned here are bit scanty, can you try to give more details here or post a new question with complete issue details and screenshot if possible [and then share the question link here] .