# Custom MSBuild target not including files in a directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild

[image]

I've added a custom msbuild target to include all the files from a certain directory however after doing a build they are still not included.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!--<Content Include="Content\lib\**\*.js" />
      <Content Include="Content\lib\**\*.css" />-->
      <Content Include="Content\lib\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

**Background**

(Trying to use bower to get components then include them in the project without having to manually add them)

[Asp.net 4.5.2, mvc 5, visual studio 2015 (update 3)]

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060870/in-a-csproj-file-what-is-none-include-for. "'Content' files are not included in a build, but are included in a publish. 'None' files are not included in a build or publish, unless they are configured that way by you", so you want to use None include instead of Content include for it to show up during a regular build.

Answer (score 2):

First Create a custom Task like below

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectAngularFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <WebFiles Include="Content\lib\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(WebFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

And then  add a property group after   `<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />` which is available in your csproj file and it will look like below. Key here is **CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn**

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
CustomCollectAngularFiles
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You should be able to see the files getting copied to the build.

For more details refer https://blog.samstephens.co.nz/2010/10/18/msbuild-including-extra-files-multiple-builds/

Comment: None of what you've put in the answer even exists in my .csproj file. From the looks of it you've just gone to some random 6 year old blog post and copied snippets into the answer.

Comment: I have been using the above target and propertygroup in my current project and deploying it to azure. You should add all of them in your csproj. Can you find <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" /> ? .Then add the above code below it, you should get the files while deploying. It works. Be patient and try and i know msBuild is frustrating until it works, once it works, you dont have to touch it again, very seemless

Comment: I don't have NuGet.targets in my .csproj at all. Also I'm not deploying to Azure. I'm trying to get these files to be automatically included in the project without having to press "right click -> include in project" essentially. So if any new file pops up in same directory content\lib then that new file is automatically included in the project at least after a build.

Comment: Hi @Euphoria   
I don't think what you are trying is possible. Modifying the self csproj file during the build process is not good practice and does not make any sense either. During build csproj is cached itself and won't be able to modify.
However, With above solution you can make sure all the excluded files are packaged and deployed to production.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that you want to include files into project by using msbuild, as far as I know, if it is the case, I think you need to use custom build task like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="Hello" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup />
    <Task>
      <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
      <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build" />
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build" />
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Evaluation" />
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Utilities" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
          <![CDATA[
        string appPath = @"C:\Projects\MsBuild\App2\App2\App2.csproj";
        var project = new Project(appPath);
        var loc = "test";
        project.AddItem("Folder", loc);
        project.Save();
        Log.LogMessage("Hello, world!", MessageImportance.High);
         ]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  ……
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.  -->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Hello />
  </Target>
  <!--<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="About to run MsBuildTask" Importance="high" />
    <App2.MsBuildTask/>
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: I will be giving this a go tonight.