# Why does VS update the project like this when creating an .editorconfig file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0

I'm adding an .editorconfig file to the project using the UI and I noticed that it creates the following entries in the project file, why?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EditorConfigFiles Remove="Z:\repos\x\Api\.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Z:\repos\x\Api\.editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I would have expected an EditorConfigFiles Include, if anything, but it moves the file to None?

Answer (score 0):

I also added .editorconfig to the C# project and the above content also appeared in the csproj file. The following two pieces of code are explained:

**Editor Config Files Remove:**

According to [How to avoid conflicts in .csproj files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file#items-and-item-groups). When you want to delete .editorconfig , the file can be removed from the project using the "delete" attribute. When you add .editorconfig, VS will not add .editorconfig in .csproj file if .editorconfig exists.

**None Include:**

According to [In a .csproj file, what is  for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060870/in-a-csproj-file-what-is-none-include-for). Because .editorconfig is not included in the project output group, nor compiled during build.

**Second update:**

Regarding being assigned to the same Itemgroup, the added activities must meet [a certain standard or condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file#items-and-item-groups). At least the module keywords used to define them need to be the same (of course there are other standards here), but let’s look at the "EditorConfigFiles Remove" and "None Include" here, which are already different keyword definitions, so this the situation is normal

Comment: It still isn't clear for me why VS removes the file from EditorConfigFiles nor why it includes the file in None. It would seem that EditorConfigFiles is an ItemGroup suitable for an .editorconfig file.

Comment: @user33276346 Hi, I updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your update. I understand that these instructions are removing the file from EditorConfigFiles and adding it to None. The question would be, why?

Comment: Why doesn't it use relative paths? Fixed paths aren't team/repo friendly.